# Can there be only one sufficient statistic when there are two parameters?

Tags: statistics

$X_1, X_2, .....X_n$ : i.i.d from $f$($x;\theta_1$, $\theta_2$)= ($1/\theta_2$)$\times $exp(-($x-\theta_1$)/$\theta_2$, $x>\theta_1$, $\theta_2>0$

First, I calculated a sufficient statistic using factorization theorem.

$f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n; \theta_1, \theta_2)= \theta_2^{-n}\times exp[-\sum(x_i-\theta_1)/\theta_2]\times I(\min(x)>\theta_1)$
= $\theta_2^{-n}\times exp[n\times\theta_1/\theta2]\times exp[-\sum x_i/\theta_2]\times I(\min(x)>\theta_1)$

$\therefore \sum x_i,  min(x)$ is S.S

however, looking at the formula, $\sum x_i$ depends on the indicator function. 
That is, it can be rewritten as one sufficient statistic ($min(x)$)

As a result, There are two parameters but one sufficient statistic.

If you ask again, should the number of parameters and the number of statistics match? ( regardless of property of S.S, C.S.S, M.S.S). 
I wonder if my conculusion is correct.

Comment: What do you mean $\sum x_i$ 'depends on the indicator function'? Here you do have a two-dimensional sufficient statistic $(\min x_i,\sum x_i)$ for the two-dimensional parameter $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$

Comment: when the indicator function is 0, the value is undefined. On the other hand, when the indicator function is 1, it is defined two sufficient statistcs. Therefore, depending on whether the value of indicator function is defined, it may or may not be expressed as "dependent". Another reason is that MLE has $\min(x)$ in $\theta_1$ and $\sum(x_i-\min(x))/n$ in $\theta_2$. I' have learned that MLE has minimum sufficient statistic. Since MLE for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ is expressed only as $\min(x)$, I think that only $\min(x)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying. By the Factorisation theorem, it is clear that for the pdf $$f_{\theta_1,\theta_2}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{1}{\theta_2^n}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{\theta_2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+n\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}\right\}I\left(\min\limits_{1\le i\le n} x_i>\theta_1\right)\,,$$ a sufficient statistic for $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is $T=(\min X_i,\sum X_i)$. The MLE of $\theta$ is a function of this sufficient statistic, that's all. And to reiterate, $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is treated as a single (vector-valued) parameter and $T$ is **a** single statistic with two components.

Comment: thank you very much answering the question!